# How to get the 1st 6months i.e.(1-26weeks) and last 6months (26-52 weeks) from last year & also get last 5weeks from current date using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How to get the 1st 6months i.e.(1-26weeks) and last 6months (26-52 weeks) from last year & also how to get last 5weeks from current date using postgresql.

Like the below table structure

```
Id Title Description current_week_number current_year
-----------------------------------------------------

123 abc  descr        48                 2021
456 def  descr1       45                 2020
```

Based on the week number and year I'm trying to fetch the data.

can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this data

Comment: Note thatPostgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Isn't the "first six months and the last six months" the same as the whole year?

Comment: I mean I'm asking seperate queries how to fetch last 1-26 Weeks (last 6 months).from currentdate and another query for  26-52 Weeks (current 6 months).
From one year how to get first 6months and how to get last 6months , need to compare from those (last6months>first 6months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
--records from 1st half of this year, based on week number
select  Id, Title, Description, current_week_number, current_year
from    your_table
where   current_year=extract('year' from now())::int
and     current_week_number<=26;
--records from 2nd half of this year, based on week number
select  Id, Title, Description, current_week_number, current_year
from    your_table
where   current_year=extract('year' from now())::int
and     current_week_number>26;
```

As to the original form of the question, getting the actual weeks:
using [`generate_series(date,date,interval)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) and [`extract('field' from date)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

```sql
with first_26_weeks_of_last_year as 
(   select extract('week' from weeks) weeks
    from generate_series(
            make_date(  extract('year' from 'today'::timestamp-'1 year'::interval)::int,
                        1,
                        1
                    ),
            make_date(  extract('year' from 'today'::timestamp-'1 year'::interval)::int,
                        1,
                        1
                    )+'25 weeks'::interval,
            '1 week'::interval) weeks),
    last_6_months_of_last_year as 
(   select extract('week' from weeks) weeks
    from generate_series(
            make_date(  extract('year' from 'today'::timestamp-'1 year'::interval)::int,
                        12,
                        31
                    ),
            make_date(  extract('year' from 'today'::timestamp-'1 year'::interval)::int,
                        12,
                        31
                    )-'6 months'::interval,
            '1 week'::interval) weeks),
    five_weeks_from_this_week as 
(   select extract('week' from weeks) weeks
    from generate_series(
            'today'::date,
            'today'::date+'4 weeks'::interval,
            '1 week'::interval) weeks)
select 'first_26_weeks_of_last_year',a.weeks
from first_26_weeks_of_last_year a
union all
select 'last_6_months_of_last_year',a.weeks
from last_6_months_of_last_year a
union all
select 'five_weeks_from_this_week',a.weeks
from five_weeks_from_this_week a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Query the table on the last 6 months until now :

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week >= Now() - interval '6 months'
   AND (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week <= Now()
```

Query the table between the last 12 months and the last 6 months from now :

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week <= Now() - interval '6 months'
   AND (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week >= Now() - interval '12 months'
```

Query the table for the first 6 months of the current year :

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week >= (extract(year from Now()) || '0101') :: date
   AND (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week <= (extract(year from Now()) || '0101') :: date + interval '6 months'
```

Query the table for the last 6 months of the current year :

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week >= (extract(year from Now()) || '0101') :: date + interval '6 months'
   AND (current_year || '0101') :: date + interval '7 days' * current_week <= (extract(year from Now()) || '0101') :: date + interval '12 months'
```